# mysql_data_seek pdo equivalent

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Which is the equivalent of mysql_data_seek using pdo objects?
Can you give me an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual answer is: do your data seek directly in the array `PDOStatement::fetchAll`... But it is WRONG IF the query fetches a lot of data (!).

There are 2 real solutions,

**1)** if database permits use  `PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS` or `PDO::FETCH_ORI_REL`,
   example,

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS, 973);
```

(EDIT) But, as commented by @ChoiZ, have a [PDO-MySQL limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12064438/287948): "MySQL does not support [cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)" (*outside* stored programs) "and the driver cannot emulate them for you"... Try later or with MySQL's forks, like MariaDB.

**2)** use the database solution (a kind of pagination). Example:

```
SELECT a, b FROM table LIMIT 1, 973
```

Comment: Yes, but, sorry, syntax was wrong, now it is corrected

Comment: No, solution #1 doesn't works with MySQL!
Please see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34625

"MySQL does not support cursors and the driver cannot emulate them for you."

Comment: Thanks @Aaroncfj the typo corrections!