# PHP PDO - Echoing only one result of select query without using a while loop

Tags: php, pdo

So far everytime i use to make a select query using pdo, i used a while loop to echo all the result. I never has a single problem. But what I am looking to do know is just echo one record. Let's say the record of the 23rd line of my table. So what I a doing is the following but  i have this error: `Notice: Undefined offset: 23 in /myFilePath/file.php`

```
$qry_que= $connexion->query('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY somefield';
$row = $qry_que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row[23]['somefield'];
```

Do note that my table has more than 100 lines... Thank you in advance for your help. Cheers. Marc.

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685871/mysql-data-seek-pdo-equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the 24th row by doing `$row[23]`.

You'll have to use a `WHERE` clause in your SQL query in order to get only the row you want.

Moreover, it will be a **lot** better on a performance point of view (think about your query when your database has 10 millions rows...)

Comment: Ok but how do use the where clause to get a line number?

Comment: I got the response in the link provided by yoshi ’SELECT a, b FROM table LIMIT 1, 973’