# how to select the rows with id's just one above gaps

Tags: php, mysql, gaps-in-data

I have a table containing columns `id` and `name`. My focus is on order of `id`. In fact I want to select the rows, When order of number's `id` breaks . Look at my example:

```
// mytable
+----+-----------+
| id |    name   |
+----+-----------+
| 1  |   ali     |
| 2  |   jack    |
| 3  |   peter   |
| 5  |   steve   |
| 6  |   lenord  |
| 7  |   jack    |
| 9  |   fered   |
+----+-----------+
```

Now I want to `select where id=5` and `select where id=9`. because `id=4` and `id=8` are removed.

**EDIT:** I want this **output:**

```
// mytable
+----+-----------+
| id |    name   |
+----+-----------+
| 5  |   steve   |
| 9  |   fered   |
+----+-----------+
```

Is it possible to I do that ?

Comment: did you mean `id=4` is removed? id=5 is alive in and well in your sample. and yes, you can use some uglyish queries to "look" around at other rows in the table.

Comment: @MarcB exactly. Then I can do that. anyway tnx

Comment: If you call an ID in your query that does not exists, you will not get results. So if you query for ids that exists, you will get results. Rows are not like Arrays. They don't re-index unless you tell them to do so. The value of the ID Column will not change when you delete a row.

Comment: @Twisty then that is impossible ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your goal. You want to collect the row that is position 4 (ID 5) and position 7 (ID 9) after the other rows are removed. This can be done.

Comment: @Strawberry What? Do you want something that I want as output ?

Comment: @Strawberry you right, I was wrong, edited.

Comment: Note: I changed the title. Integrity is *not lost* when there a few gaps in the range of ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you want the records with id's just one above the *missing* id's; so you need to search fo the records with `id` such that `id-1` does **not exist** (this will always be the case for the lowest id, so we'll have to explicitely exclude `id=1` )

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table tt
WHERE id > 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM the_table nx
   WHERE nx.id = tt.id -1
   );
```

Comment: OW MY GOD !!! HOW ?? I thought I know `sql` but ...!!! Thanks !
Just I can't understand it, Can explain me more about your code ?!

Comment: Have a new question, Why I can't use `NOT IN` instead of `NOT EXISTS` ?

Comment: You probably can, but why should you?

Comment: I checked it and did not work, there is not mandatory. I just like to know why `NOT IN` does not work ?!

Answer (score 0):

Try seeking versus a specific ID.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

```
<?php
/* Open a connection */
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT id, name FROM table";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* seek to row no. 4 */
    $result->data_seek(3);

    /* fetch row */
    $row = $result->fetch_row();

    printf ("ID: %s  Name: %s\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

    /* seek to row no. 7 */
    $result->data_seek(6);

    /* fetch row */
    $row = $result->fetch_row();

    printf ("ID: %s  Name: %s\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

    /* free result set*/
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

This should return:

```
ID: 5 Name: steve
ID: 9 Name: fered
```

Comment: Did you seek manually ? In reality my table has +10000 rows. I need to a automatic algorithm. And by the way, `data_seek();` is just for **mysqli**? I'm using **PDO**

Comment: You did not clarify what functions you were using. You did not explain the issue with enough details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685871/mysql-data-seek-pdo-equivalent

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id - 1 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL 
   AND x.id > 1;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  5 | steve | 
|  9 | fered | 
+----+-------+
```

Comment: I checked your code and did not see two columns `id` and `name` contained `NULL`. what are that ? You select `x.*`, Then I don't think there be more two columns.